# References on coefficient quivers

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, definitions, quivers

I would like to study about coefficient quivers, but I cannot find a good reference, as book for example. I could find many papers working with coefficient quivers, but none of them give a book or a "initial" paper with the definition and (basic) properties of coefficient quivers.

Can someone help me by giving some (good) references where I can learn about coefficient quivers?

Any suggestion is welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

See the top of the second page of Ringel, "Exceptional modules are tree modules" (1998) for example.